# Python: get latitude/ longitude of a pixel location in an image, if corner coordinates are known

Tags: python, image, geolocation, rasterio, satellite-image

I have a satellite SAR image (Iceye GRD)(s. img below) and in its metadata the latitude/ longitude for each of the four image corners are given, i.e.:

`image pixel    -> georef. location`

`[1, 1]         -> [1.6033675891108876, 104.05738201292307]`

`[16892, 1]     -> [1.5291001811499518, 104.42831446776263]`

`[1, 26855]     -> [1.0079111030191064, 103.93758132038617]`

`[16892, 26855] -> [0.9334645684110325, 104.30991666976476]`

[example SAR image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJs3.png)

I also know it's using WGS84 as a georeference system, but there's no specific src given.

What's the best way to write a funtion, which returns the real world coordinate for a given pixel coordinate, so for example the latitude/ longitude for (10000, 200000)? Is there a lightweight python module capable of doing this?

I tried opening the transform using rasterio, but its .transform simply returns a matrix filled with ones, so calling it results in pixel location = georef. location.

Comment: hi, I am also trying to do this, did you figure it out?